# Exporting Passwords from Cain

Tags: security, passwords, export, sniffer, man-in-the-middle

Is it possible to automatically export passwords sniffed with Cain to a text file, so that they may be used for another purpose?

If Cain doesn't allow this, is there a tool that does?

Comment: Stackoverflow is about code. Please post the code you have tried and tell in what way it is not meeting your expectations.

Answer (score 1):

all data saved in installation directory (.LST),
 u can open it with notePad++

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there is a way to export these passwords to a text file.

According to
https://www.nebrija.es/~cmalagon/seguridad_informatica/transparencias/cainAbel.pdf

Right click highlighted passwords and choose Export. Name it what you will and it should export it to a text file